# python multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count: causes forever loop

Tags: python, scipy, multiprocessing

The code using multiprocessing causes a forever loop.

I'm using a building an iris recognition system. this is the `matching` function. everything works fine until the `multiprocessing` the part.

I'm attaching screenshot of the error output below so that you get a better idea.

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

**Code:**

```
##-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
##  Import
##-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from fnmatch import filter
import scipy.io as sio
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from itertools import repeat

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


##-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
##  Function
##-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def matching(template_extr, mask_extr, temp_dir, threshold=0.38):
    """
    Description:
        Match the extracted template with database.

    Input:
        template_extr   - Extracted template.
        mask_extr       - Extracted mask.
        threshold       - Threshold of distance.
        temp_dir        - Directory contains templates.

    Output:
        List of strings of matched files, 0 if not, -1 if no registered sample.
    """
    # Get the number of accounts in the database
    n_files = len(filter(listdir(temp_dir), '*.mat'))
    if n_files == 0:
        return -1

    # Use all cores to calculate Hamming distances
    args = zip(
        sorted(listdir(temp_dir)),
        repeat(template_extr),
        repeat(mask_extr),
        repeat(temp_dir),
    )
    with Pool(processes=cpu_count()) as pools:
        result_list = pools.starmap(matchingPool, args)

    filenames = [result_list[i][0] for i in range(len(result_list))]
    hm_dists = np.array([result_list[i][1] for i in range(len(result_list))])

    # Remove NaN elements
    ind_valid = np.where(hm_dists>0)[0]
    hm_dists = hm_dists[ind_valid]
    filenames = [filenames[idx] for idx in ind_valid]

    # Threshold and give the result ID
    ind_thres = np.where(hm_dists<=threshold)[0]

    # Return
    if len(ind_thres)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        hm_dists = hm_dists[ind_thres]
        filenames = [filenames[idx] for idx in ind_thres]
        ind_sort = np.argsort(hm_dists)
        return [filenames[idx] for idx in ind_sort]


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def calHammingDist(template1, mask1, template2, mask2):
    """
    Description:
        Calculate the Hamming distance between two iris templates.

    Input:
        template1   - The first template.
        mask1       - The first noise mask.
        template2   - The second template.
        mask2       - The second noise mask.

    Output:
        hd          - The Hamming distance as a ratio.
    """
    # Initialize
    hd = np.nan

    # Shift template left and right, use the lowest Hamming distance
    for shifts in range(-8,9):
        template1s = shiftbits(template1, shifts)
        mask1s = shiftbits(mask1, shifts)

        mask = np.logical_or(mask1s, mask2)
        nummaskbits = np.sum(mask==1)
        totalbits = template1s.size - nummaskbits

        C = np.logical_xor(template1s, template2)
        C = np.logical_and(C, np.logical_not(mask))
        bitsdiff = np.sum(C==1)

        if totalbits==0:
            hd = np.nan
        else:
            hd1 = bitsdiff / totalbits
            if hd1 < hd or np.isnan(hd):
                hd = hd1

    # Return
    return hd


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def shiftbits(template, noshifts):
    """
    Description:
        Shift the bit-wise iris patterns.

    Input:
        template    - The template to be shifted.
        noshifts    - The number of shift operators, positive for right
                      direction and negative for left direction.

    Output:
        templatenew - The shifted template.
    """
    # Initialize
    templatenew = np.zeros(template.shape)
    width = template.shape[1]
    s = 2 * np.abs(noshifts)
    p = width - s

    # Shift
    if noshifts == 0:
        templatenew = template

    elif noshifts < 0:
        x = np.arange(p)
        templatenew[:, x] = template[:, s + x]
        x = np.arange(p, width)
        templatenew[:, x] = template[:, x - p]

    else:
        x = np.arange(s, width)
        templatenew[:, x] = template[:, x - s]
        x = np.arange(s)
        templatenew[:, x] = template[:, p + x]

    # Return
    return templatenew


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def matchingPool(file_temp_name, template_extr, mask_extr, temp_dir):
    """
    Description:
        Perform matching session within a Pool of parallel computation

    Input:
        file_temp_name  - File name of the examining template
        template_extr   - Extracted template
        mask_extr       - Extracted mask of noise

    Output:
        hm_dist         - Hamming distance
    """
    # Load each account
    data_template = sio.loadmat('%s%s'% (temp_dir, file_temp_name))
    template = data_template['template']
    mask = data_template['mask']

    # Calculate the Hamming distance
    hm_dist = calHammingDist(template_extr, mask_extr, template, mask)
    return (file_temp_name, hm_dist)
```

how can I remove multiprocessing and make code still work fine?

[screenshots dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pupxlj28rls2759/AADmJFetUogNRZ7Ya22xWT8Ba?dl=0)

Comment: Please post you output as text. Screenshots of text are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python's `itertools.starmap()`

hope it helps

Comment: Hi, That would be a greater answer why your answer solved the problem for the question.
Best.